# Чтение/запись большого количества json файлов

Tags: python, база-данных, json, python-3.x

Для последующего анализа данных, мне нужно получать с api ответов json, весом, сохранённом в текстовом формате ~2.7 мегабайт за каждый. Таких файлов 200-250 тысяч. Вопрос - как хранить и читать. Подскажите пожалуйста оптимальный на ваш взгляд способ.

Сейчас моё решение в том, чтобы использовать модуль gzip (Python 3.6) для сжатия одного большого файла, содержащего в каждой строчке по json ответу. Записывается и читается каждая строка итеративно (плюсуя в конец перенос строки "\n"), не требуя загрузки в оперативку всего файла.
Таким образом в пересчёте на каждый файл 2.7 мб сжимается в 150 кб.
Вопрос - есть ли более удобное решение именно для скорости чтения/записи?

```
import gzip
import json
from requests import get

with gzip.open('large_data.json.gz', 'wb') as outfile:
    while True:
        response = get(url).json()
        outfile.write(json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8') + b'\n')
```

Comment: Можно чуть компактнее в [bson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson) хранить/обрабатывать. Но если главное - небольшой объем - то, конечно, компрессировить.

Comment: "оптимальность" в разных обстоятельствах разные вещи означает. Ответ на вопрос "можно ли быстрее" всегда положительный — вопрос сколько времени, усилий и необходимых ресурсов вы готовы потратить. Чтобы вопрос был бы ещё кому-нибудь полезен: попробуйте более конкретную цель указать: к примеру: «вот код(+входные данные), который на таком-то железе за X минут выполняется, как сделать чтобы за X/2 минут выполнялся на том же железе(шпиндельный диск,SSD), версиях ПО(python,OS)» Результаты измерений, которые указывают где узкое место: преобразование в json, сжатие, запись на диск, не помешают.

Comment: Маппинг - не...?

Comment: @And Попробуйте перечитать то, что вы написали. "Преобразование - не...?". Или вы хотели сказать "Топографическая съёмка - не...?". И что из этого понимать? Вы хотели напомнить про объектно-реляционное отображение или просто вам нравится это слово и вы его используете для непонятно чего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При ваших объемах данных есть смысл задуматься об использовании Hadoop Cluster и Apache Spark (обычно это часть Hadoop Cluster) для параллельной обработки данных.

Я бы поступил слудующим образом:

1. на лету преобразуем JSON's в Parquet (+Snappy compression - очень быстрый для "разжатия") и сохраняем на HDFS (распределенная кластерная файловая система). Стоит также попробовать объединять файлы (по дням, месяцам или другим параметрам) - HDFS гораздо эффективнее работает с меньшим числом больших файлов чем с большим числом маленьких.
2. для обработки данных в Hadoop Cluster можно использовать Apache Spark (поддерживает след. языки: Scala, Python, Java) и/или Hive/Impala.

Hadoop Cluster можно строить из относительно дешевого железа - он лучше скалируется горизонтально чем вертикально - т.е. лучше больше серверов с меньшими ресурсами (RAM, CPU, IO) чем малое к-во оч. мощных серверов. Еще не рекомендуется использовать сервера с большим (512GiB+) объемом RAM, т.к. почти все компоненты Hadoop Cluster написаны на Java и при сборке мусора (garbage collection) при больших JVM могут возникать пиковые нагрузки.

PS `gzip` - при хороших показателях сжатия является очень медленным как для сжатия так и для распаковки.

**UPDATE:**

если у вас не планируется "взрывного" роста объема данных, то можно начать с чего-нибудь попроще, например один из следующих вариантов:

- складывать данные в БД (некоторые БД поддерживают компрессию)
- хранить данные в HDF5 (поддерживает доступ к данным по индексам, т.е. с диска читается только индекс и те данные, которые удовлетворяют условию) в связке с [Pandas (если у вас достаточно памяти)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) или [Dask Dataframe (позволяет работать с данными, которые не помещаются в RAM)](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html). Оба варианта поддерживают чтение JSON. Также [HDF5 поддерживает разные алгоритмы сжатия данных (`zlib`, `lzo`, `bzip2`, `blosc`, `zlib`)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html). Pandas и Dask DataFrame имеют очень схожий API и идеологию с Apache Spark. Т.е. когда вы осознаете, что вам уже пора переходить на Apache Spark - переход будет не таким болезненным/сложным.

Comment: при относительно небольшом объёме данных, которые легко на ноутбуке помещаются (сотни гигабайт), использование таких вещей как hadoop может затормозить процесс. [Don't use Hadoop - your data isn't that big](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/hadoop_hatred.html)

Comment: @jfs, наверное так и есть при нынешних объемах, но данные имеют свойство нелинейно расти и накапливаться. Пример из личной профессиональной жизни - мы начали внедрять Hadoop когда уже "уперлись" в ограничения на стороне RDBMS (Oracle RAC Cluster) и если бы мы начали на несколько лет раньше мы могли бы избежать целового ряда неприятных проблем...

Comment: чаще у начинающих профессиональных программистов обратная проблема: слишком много уровней абстракции навешивают (про принципу, используй всё что имею -- вне зависимости имеет ли это смысл для выбранной задачи или нет). Следует использовать самое простое решение, которое работает и не плодить сущностей сверх необходимого.